# FQL: Get comment data WHERE object_id={a known object_id} works, but WHERE id={a known comment XID} does not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I'm using FQL to get comment data from webpage with a Facebook comment box.  I use the graph to get the object_id, then use FQL to get all comments with that object_id.  However, if I want to pull data from a specific comment using its id (sometimes referred to as an XID) the FQL returns 0 results.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/ the id should be indexed, so this query should work:

```
SELECT+id,+text,+time,+fromid,+is_private+FROM+comment+WHERE+id={some known XID}
```

But it doesn't.  BTW, *THIS* query does work:

```
SELECT+id,+text,+time,+fromid,+is_private+FROM+comment+WHERE+object_id={some known object_id}
```

It is irritating how I can't pull query for comments using time or fromid or anything other than object_id, id, post_id, and parent_id... but in practice only using the object_id returns anything.

has anyone else run into this problem?  Is my XID query wrong somehow, or is the id only indexed on certain kinds of comments, and not webpage comments for no inexplicable reason?

Answer (score 0):

This one I managed to solve with trial and error. I had to put the id in single quotes. It's odd, I could query the object_id without putting it in quotes, but not the id. This is sort of what the working FQL looked like, except with a valid access token:

```
SELECT+id,+text,+time,+fromid,+is_private+FROM+comment+WHERE+id='#########_####'
```

as opposed to:

```
SELECT+id,+text,+time,+fromid,+is_private+FROM+comment+WHERE+id=#########_####
```

which failed to return any results.

Thanks for being consistent, Facebook :(